# Identifying the id of current visible div

Tags: javascript

I am working with 3 divs at the moment - on pageLoad the default is viewed but when the user clicks on a button the div is hidden and the selected div appears in its place.

How would I write an if statement to identify the div currently selected by the user? For example:

```
if selected_div is 'dpara' then ....

else if selected_div is dtab then ....
```

Thanks in advance!

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function arrange(div_id) {
            // First make all the divs hidden...
            divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
            for( var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ) {
                divs[i].style.display = 'none';
            }

            // Now make the one we want to be visible visible...
            document.getElementById(div_id).style.display = 'block';
        }
    </script>
    <form>
        <input type='button' value='dpara' onclick='arrange(this.value);' />
        <input type='button' value='dtab' onclick='arrange(this.value);' />
        <input type='button' value='ddl' onclick='arrange(this.value);' />
    </form>
    <div id='dpara'>
    </div>

    <div id='dtab' style='display: none'>
    </div>

    <div id='ddl' style='display: none'>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're already going through a function for each button click you could just keep the visible `div` in a variable, something like:

```
var visibleDiv;

function arrange(divId) {
    // Cache the passed in 'div' as the currently visible one
    visibleDiv = document.getElementById(divId);

    // First make all the divs hidden...
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
        i,
        len;

    for (i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++) {
        divs[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    // Now make the one we want to be visible visible...
    visibleDiv.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend that you implement a JS libarry that will help you do this across browsers. For example JQuery can determine what is visible as described here...

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: do you have any purely JavaScript examples I can use. I am new to JavaScript.

Comment: jakeclarkson's example looks sensible as long as you're only using `display:none` to hide your divs. If your code also uses `visibility:hidden` you'll have to code for that as well [CSS display vs Visibiltiy](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp). I still recommend using JQuery though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Identify the `div`s at startup and assign a new function to them:

```
$('#dpara')[0].myFunc = function() { ... }
$('#dtab')[0].myFunc = function() { ... }
```

Now you can

```
selected_div.myFunc();
```

How to find the selected div? Use a `:visible` selector:

```
$('div:visible')[0].myFunc();
```

PS: The `[0]` gets the DOM element from the jQuery list.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this without the use of jQuery?

Comment: Sure. Just use the standard JS methods to locate DOM elements by ID. For the last part, you'll need a loop over all three divs (maybe save them in an array) or save the selected div in a global variable when you switch to it.